# How i can get selected date in react-datepicker with formik form?

Tags: reactjs, formik

I am using Formik and react-datepicker in it.
When I select the date and hit submit the form it shows `"startDate": ''` and when I change `initialValues={{ startDate: '' }}` to `initialValues={{ startDate: this.state.startDate }}` then it shows the today date (current date).
But I want to get the selected date.

```
//import libraries
import React from 'react'
import { Formik, Form } from 'formik'
import DatePicker from "react-datepicker"
import "react-datepicker/dist/react-datepicker.css";

//Class component
export default class InsertStockComponent extends React.Component {
  state = {
    startDate: new Date()
  }

  handleChange = (date) => {
    this.setState({
      startDate: date
    });
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div id="main-content">
        <Formik
          initialValues={{ startDate: '' }}

          onSubmit={(values, { setSubmitting }) => {
            setTimeout(() => {
              alert(JSON.stringify(values, null, 2));
              setSubmitting(false);
            }, 400);
          }}

        >
          {({ isSubmitting }) => (

            <div className="row clearfix">
                  <div className="header">
                  </div>
                    <Form>
                      <div className="row ml-4 mr-4">
                        <div className="form-group col-3 mb-2">

                          <DatePicker selected={this.state.startDate} dateFormat="MMMM d, yyyy" className="form-control" name="startDate" onChange={this.handleChange} />
                        </div>

                      </div>
                      <div className="row mb-3">
                        <div className="col-5 mb-4"></div>
                        <button type="submit" className="btn btn-lg btn-outline-success mt-4 mb-4" disabled={isSubmitting}>insert item</button>
                      </div>
                    </Form>
                  </div>
          )}
        </Formik>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

### Solution

I created a working example for you here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/demo-react-formik-datepicker

Have a look. Continue reading for the explanation.

### Explanation

`Formik` is used to manage state of your form. So you do not need to define your own state as `Formik` provides you with the utilities to do that. Therefore you can safely remove this piece of code:

```
 state = {
    startDate: new Date()
 }

 handleChange = (date) => {
    this.setState({
      startDate: date
    });
 }
```

And instead, manage your state using `values.startDate` and `setFieldValue` both of which are provided by `Formik` based on the `initialValues` that you pass to it.

Comment: thanks it's working, it gives output like this `startDate: 2019-07-25T17:25:38.201Z`...What if I want to get output like `startDate: 2019-07-25` OR `startDate: 25-07-2019` ??

Comment: Use `date-fns` package. Its `format` function is very simple to use. https://date-fns.org/